# Struggling horizontally centering a button - after a absolute positioned item

Tags: html, css, position

Im trying to horizontally center this button to match the attached image.

I have it posted here
http://danux.me/

It does come after an absolutely positioned item with a z-index of 2. I am awful at the idea of positioning and surprised having those tiles overlap the blue bar worked, however, I'm not sure why the button won't appear below it.

The tiles also have an interaction in it (also surprised I could get this to work too after swiping the code) so maybe that has something to do with it?

Any guesses?

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside a container with `clear: both`. This is called a [clearfix](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html).

```
<div style="clear: both">
  <a href="#" class="button"></a>
</div>
```

I couldn't find the absolutely positioned element you're referring to. `#home_console_wrapper` has `position: relative`. You definitely want relative, not absolute, since giving an element `position: absolute` makes it float on top of other elements instead of pushing them down.

Comment: Thanks. I had had one in there because I had some floats that I ended up being able to remove. But I did add the clear back in with no effect. (Good to know though that clears "push down" relative positioned items like they do to floats."  (And, yes, I was mistaken. The tiled cube is relative. The blue bar at the top was absolute.)

Comment: It does bump it down, but I have other issues now. Thanks jSepia!